# Поиск по хештегам

Tags: веб-программирование

Делаю поиск по хештегам, сылка на поиск выглядит так : `http://example.com/search/#хештег` но браузер воспринимает `#хештег` как "якорь", как можно сделать чтобы он не воспринимался как якорь?

Comment: Не использовать символ `#`?

Comment: Все спицсимволы в URL должны быть кодированы, `#` надо кодировать как `%23`